# Skip or I'm Done after substantially improving a question that probably still needs more work?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

Oftentimes in FP I'll run across a question that is in terrible shape: mistagged, filled with bad English, and with the most vague title possible. I then whip it into shape with a suggested edit and there we go.

However, it's quite possible that it could still use a good deal more work. Maybe the retag or title rephrasing exposes a duplicate in related or the dupe flagger that would otherwise be hard to find. Or maybe a subject-matter expert can now see that it's trivially a typo. Or whatever.

Point is, I've made the question *better*, but haven't necessarily *fixed all the everything wrong with it* *. What button should I hit in the review UI at this point? <kbd>Skip</kbd>, to give someone else a pass at it? <kbd>I'm Done</kbd>, because, well, I'm done?

(Some of the same questions apply to LA, and presumably to VLQ, but the latter I have of course no access to just yet.)

<sub>* Yes, I know that's bad grammar.</sub>

Comment: ...there are 30,000 users eligible to complete review if you skip